# How to install wxpython without errors?

Tags: python, pip, wxpython

Collecting wxpython
Using cached wxPython-4.2.0.tar.gz (71.0 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [12 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\Saveliy Levchenko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jlsrzw9j\wxpython_57232c39b5904dcb8d9c75d92e503a20\setup.py", line 27, in 
from buildtools.config import Config, msg, opj, runcmd, canGetSOName, getSOName
File "C:\Users\Saveliy Levchenko\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jlsrzw9j\wxpython_57232c39b5904dcb8d9c75d92e503a20\buildtools\config.py", line 30, in 
from attrdict import AttrDict
File "C:\Users\Saveliy Levchenko\Documents\Programing\IUTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\attrdict_*init*_.py", line 5, in 
from attrdict.mapping import AttrMap
File "C:\Users\Saveliy Levchenko\Documents\Programing\IUTest\venv\Lib\site-packages\attrdict\mapping.py", line 4, in 
from collections import Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\collections_*init*_.py)
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

Comment: you can see the steps here -

https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython